# Преобразование URL

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли переделать вот такие URL скриптов на сайте

http://www.site.com/inner.php?razdel=company&razdel_title=Клиентам&id=2

в какие-то такие, например:

http://www.site.com/inner.php/company/Клиентам/2

Т.е., чтобы в адресной строке отображался второй вариант, а в  скрипте обрабатывался, как первый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

код .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /inner.php?razdel=$1&razdel_title=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

либо

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^inner\.php\/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /inner.php?razdel=$1&razdel_title=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Писал "на коленке", проверить негде пока :(

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Что-то не получается. Стала пробовать немного на др. УРЛ, правда.
.htaccess получился такой:
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /inner.php?t=$1&url=$2 [L]

С помощью него пыталась преобразовать урл
http://www.site.ru/inner.php/o_kompanii/О компании    
в
http://www.site.ru/inner.php?t=o_kompanii&url=О компании
Похоже, преобразования не происходит,параметры вообще не видятся.

Comment: Нет, преобразование всё-таки происходит. Например, файл css перестал подключаться (<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index.css">), вместо него подключается тоже inner.php

Comment: попробуйте href="/style/index.css"

Comment: nolka, спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Переходите [по этой ссылочке](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/), указываете оригинальный URL, корректируете параметры и на выходе, получаете правило. Аналогичные действия, можно проделать и [на этом ресурсе](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml)

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо, генераторы очень помогли.